# how to validate uniqueness for custom scope active-record rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a model(`Verification`) that I'm trying to validate uniqueness for.

However, I need to scope the uniqueness to the status(enum) as follow:

```
class Verification < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :profile

  scope :active, -> { where('status NOT IN (?)',
                            ['approved', 'rejected'].map{ |s| self.statuses[s]
                            }
  ) }

  validates :profile, uniqueness: { scope: :active,
                                    message: "can have only one active per time." }

  enum status: [:requested, :processing, :approved, :rejected]

end
```

I don't want a profile to have more than one active verification at a time.

but when I do it like above, it raises an error since there is no column named `active` in my `verifications` table.

How can I validate uniqueness of profile scoped only for active verifications? thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the `scope` keyword in a uniqueness validation isn't the same thing as a Rails `scope`.. it's more related to SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the scope keyword in a uniqueness validation isn't the same thing as a Rails scope.. it's more related to SQL, and is generally restricted to just an attribute name (or set of attribute names).

Looks like you also might be able to pass a block in via `conditions` eg:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :profile, conditions: -> {  
  where('status NOT IN (?)',
         ['approved', 'rejected'].map{ |s| self.statuses[s] }
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks... I think you are correct, I can pass in condition, but looks like the syntax of the conditional is not right... I can't figure it out yet... I have the error: `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>` and the whole class breaks. I think the conditional should be a `key=>value` pair. checking...

Comment: So... I got it... `validates_uniqueness_of :profile, conditions: -> {}`. thanks.

Comment: oops yes that should be a "stabby lambda" not just a block ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try with a proc.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :profile, :scope => :status, unless: Proc.new { |verification| verification.status == 'approved' || verification.status == 'rejected'}
```

Comment: Thanks... on trying this, I got an `ArgumentError` error: `ArgumentError: Unknown validator: 'UniqueValidator`

Comment: This is not different from what I have in the question. This will look for an `active` column in the `verifications` table, of which there is none, and it throws a `PG::UndefinedColumn` error accordingly.

Comment: I have posted that mistakenly, updated the ans, pls try using a proc.

Comment: Hmm... this is not taking the proc into account. It's only validating uniqueness of status.